# Laying out divs of different heights in a grid

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a site that I'd like to layout like this image:

[image: Desktop:A B/C D/E F Mobile: A B C D E F]

Red is the desktop version and yellow is the mobile version. I can easily switch between the two using media queries.

My problem is how to write the CSS for the desktop version - I only include the mobile version because the layout precludes some layout techniques for the desktop version.

The content within each pair (e.g. A and B) can be of different heights, but they're similar enough that I'd like to lay them out as equal heights so the next pairs headers line up.

The easiest way I guess is to hardcode the heights for each pair, but I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Comment: Would you rather rely on Javascript, or rather add non-semantic wrappers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a container for those elements.

for example a `<ul>` and the elements themselves be `<li>` elements.

example **html**

```
<ul class="container">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
    <li>F</li>
</ul>
```

**desktop CSS**

```
ul.container li{
  width:45%;
  margin-right:5%;
  float:left;
}

ul.container li:nth-child(odd){
  clear:left;
}
```

**mobile CSS**

```
ul.container li{
  width:100%;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/AgNjB/1

---

**notice**

The above code works if you only want to line-up their headers (*the left and right **tops** are at the same place*). But it will need alterations if you want their actual height to line up as well (*for a bottom border for instance*)..

Comment: @Omeid, any tag will do .. I just thought from the mock-ups that semantically a `ul` and `li`s seem appropriate..

Comment: I hadn't considered using nth-child(odd) to clear them. Cheers!

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli , Yup I just wanted to mention that for OP. :D

Comment: @ICR, not that it `:nth-child` will not work for pre-IE9 versions.. for previous versions of IE you will have to attach a class to the odd ones and use that clear them.. (*or use javascript to target those..*)

Comment: however semantically a ul and li is not appropriate for layout, and you better go with divs.

Comment: @omeid, well.. if a,b,c,d,e,.. are a list .. :)

Comment: Just as a sidenote, I found it better to add 2.5% margin to the left and right which then centers the content better.

Comment: I used sections for the elements themselves.

Comment: @Icr, of'course you can use whatever margins you need (*or none..*) Mine were for illustration only.. just make sure it adds up to 100%..